# Nautilus to open URIs in tabs via terminal?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

`caja` has `-t` or `--tabs` options to open URIs in tabs via terminal.

e.g.

```
wolf@linux:~$ caja -t /etc /var
wolf@linux:~$ nautilus -t /etc /var
Unknown option -t
wolf@linux:~$
```

Can the same thing be done with `nautilus`? There is no `-t` in it. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: We don't know your OS &  release (thus version of `nautilus` being used), but I don't see a `-t` option when I `man nautilus` (ie. view the reference manual for my own release)

Comment: Looks like this has not been added to nautilus to support it but it has been requested:  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633338 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

No.
There is [no such option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man1/nautilus.1.html) in the Nautilus and it demonstrates its illness as in case with missing extra pane (accessible in Caja by <kbd>F3</kbd>).

Simply use [Caja](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man1/caja.1.html) instead, or use whole MATE Desktop for the best user experience.